# Send Marketing Cloud Email From Salesforce

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud

I have my Sales cloud org connected and configured with the Marketing cloud Org.
How can we send a Marketing Cloud email from Sales cloud using apex code and not from Marketing cloud connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a triggered send:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_triggered_sends.htm&type=5

This link has plenty of information on setting up a trigger and configureing the send. This does require that you have the marketing cloud connector installed as it sends through the connector but doesn't require you to send the email manually through the UI. You can trigger the send via apex.

Comment: If I want to send Marketing cloud email based on what was the value before and after update of the record, can we achieve this using Triggered sends.

Comment: That would be a bit trickier. I believe it's based on just the record but if you created fields to store "previous values" and updated those in your trigger prior to sending the email, you could probably figure out a way to make it work.